# Calculating and improving the number of requests/concurrent users my webserver can handle?

Tags: webserver, scalability, load-testing

I am building a dynamic website and app using HTML/Javascript/PHP/mysql. I have
completed the site and my main focus is now ensuring that when it is launched it is
not taken down by the traffic I am hoping to receive. (I predict around 5000-7000 unique visits on launch day).

The website is currently live, you can see it here : http://www.nightmapper.com/

My hosting is provided by bhost and I am on there silver VPS package:

1024MB Guaranteed Memory, 
1536MB Burst Memory, 
4 Virtual Cores, 
40GB Disk Space, 
750GB Data Transfer, 
1 IPv4 Addresses

I manage the server myself, but I'm fairly new to it.

Anyway, the most computationally expensive page is the index/home page, on this
page I have 10 mySql queries, which are (mostly) used to get this weeks venue
listings. The listing results are each displayed with a thumbnail image.

the size of the home page for a first time visit is: 2.7mb, I have done
everything I can think of to minimize this including generating thumbnails to
reduce image size and utilizing browser caching.

I have tried a couple methods for stress testing the site including load impact: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zn6Sq.jpg

and ab testing in terminal. I am worried by the results (mostly
with the result of 5.26 requests per second, which appears to be quite a low):

```
ab -n 100 -c 10 http://www.nightmapper.com/

This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 655654 $>
Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/
Licensed to The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/
Benchmarking www.nightmapper.com (be patient).....done

Server Software:        Apache/2.2.22
Server Hostname:        www.nightmapper.com
Server Port:            80
Document Path:          /
Document Length:        44808 bytes
Concurrency Level:      10
Time taken for tests:  19.012 seconds
Complete requests:      100
Failed requests:        0
Write errors:          0
Total transferred:      4519300 bytes
HTML transferred:      4480800 bytes
Requests per second:    5.26 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:      1901.199 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:      190.120 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          232.14 [Kbytes/sec] received


Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median  max
Connect:      26  38  17.9    32    107
Processing:  933 1828 510.2  1782    3495
Waiting:      22  116 303.4    28    1601
Total:        967 1867 518.8  1813    3591


Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%  1813
  66%  1983
  75%  2032
  80%  2184
  90%  2412
  95%  3124
  98%  3568
  99%  3591
 100%  3591 (longest request)
```

Using these results, how can I calculate the number of unique visitors a day and concurrent users I can handle, and which methods can I use to identify problems and improve on these results?

I should probably take this opportunity to ask for any good resources;
where I can learn more about such optimization, load testing and Scalability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a complex problem, as there are many factors involved. Here are some things I would investigate:

- Your home page as you state is very large, that is going to be a problem. You could look at a caching service for the images, that could help a lot (something like Amazon Cloudfront: https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/). This type of content delivery service copies your images to "edge" locations, and takes the burden off of your Web server for downloading those. It could make a very big difference. I would guess that this is the biggest portion of your content, so removing this from your Web server will make things much faster.
- The next thing you mention is that you are performing 10 MySQL queries on the home page load, that is a lot of individual queries. If you can restructure your data model or queries to get it down to 1 or 2 queries, it will probably be much faster.
- The other option you could try is some sort of paging scheme on the Web page, as the user scrolls down you can perform individual MySQL queries for each portion as it becomes visible.
- It seems like you are running on a single server now, an easy thing to do is to run on at least 2 servers (1 for your Web server, 1 for MySQL). MySQL consumes a lot of memory and CPU when it gets busy, so isolating that is recommended.
- For scaling your application server that is easy, you can use a load balancer and have many app server instances.
- Scaling the database tier is more challenging, there are several ways to do that, including read-balancing (using MySQL replication to a read-only slave). After simple read-balancing it gets into sharding, but I doubt you will need that as it does not appear that you have a lot of database writes, or a very big data set. If you do get into a situation with high write volumes and very large data (50GB - 1TB), then sharding is worth looking into.

To estimate the number of users you can handle should be simple to figure out. There is a book I wrote called Software Pipelines which talks about approaches for doing this ([http://www.amazon.com/Software-Pipelines-SOA-Multi-Core-Processing/dp/0137137974](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0137137974)). The basic idea is to identify how long each step in your processing is taking, and compute that against the peak traffic you expect. You have the crude figures to do that now even with your current implementation. For example if you can do 5 loads of the home page/second, and you expect 7000 users/day, then just calculate the peak traffic. On average 7000 users/day (with 1 home page load each) is only about 5 page requests/minute. Therefore, even if your peak load is 10X that number, you should be able to handle the load.

The key is to understand and profile your application to see where the time is being spent, then apply one or more of the approaches outlined above.

Good luck with your site!

Comment: thankyou for your response! your book looks fantastic, I am going to look into it